# creating a multidimensional array and fill it

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I want to draw a graph on my page and would like to use Charts.js. The Documentation on

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

says that the Chars I want to create needs an Array of Labels like this:

```
var data = {

    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
        }
    ]
}
```

1. Question: How do I create such a Array?
2. Question: How can I fill this array with the Input of a Textfield?

Thanks!
Jan

Comment: You create the array by writing it like this in JavaScript… how else do you want to create it? Do you have the data coming from somewhere? How exactly would your textfield look like, i.e., what should users enter?

Answer (score 1):

A1) The way you have written is the right way to create arrays in javascript

A2) Suppose you have a textfield with `id='month'`. You can access its value like this:

```
var month = document.getElementById('month').value
```

Next you can create an array `var label = [];` and add the data from the text field by pushing in the array. i.e `label.push(month)`

Once you have populated the array for `label`, you can assign this array to property `labels` of your `data` object.

Similarly to assign values to data, create an array `var values = []; var values2 = [];` Now populate the `values` and `values2` array by pushing values into it.

```
var label = [];
var values = []; 
var values2 = [];
var month = document.getElementById('month').value;  
//keep on doing this for all input fields
label.push(month)
//similarly push data into values and values2.
//Now build your structure for chart as follows:
var data = {

    labels : label,
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : values
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : values2
        }
    ]
}
```

Here `label` , `values` and `values2` are the arrays you got from your textfields.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Different case as in? I just gave an example for the labels array, so the user can proceed further to solve his query.

Comment: Yes this is how the user has to proceed, but user seems like a beginner, we have to help

Comment: As far my knowledge, First where have to define the structure and then start push the elements, wait I 'll post one example

Answer (score 0):

define something like this{

```
data = {
        label:""
        fields: [],     
};
```

push the value

```
data.fields.push({
        label: "label", 
        value: "your constructed value"
        });
```